# Paint event: How to draw image in separate library then draw with Graphics object

Tags: vb.net, winforms, system.drawing

I have an application that draws engineering diagrams on a portion of the screen. Right now the logic for drawing the diagram is in the Paint event. I would like to separate that out into another project.

Is the best way to pass the dimensions of the bitmap I need (along with diagram info) and get an image returned and then use the Graphics context to paint the bitmap?

If so, how do I get the dimensions of the draw area to pass to the drawing code that will generate the bitmap at the appropriate size?

Thanks!

Comment: I think maybe the answer to my question is what ever the size of the area of the control I want to draw on. It could be Me.Width and Me.Height....or a smaller area within that. It's the object that implements the Paint method I should get this from, not the Graphics context.

Comment: In the event handler, the `sender` parameter is the object that raised the event. You can cast that as type `Control` and then get the `Size` or individual `Width` and `Height` properties from that.

Comment: @jmcilhinney In practice, the actual available area on the control might differ from that. You should probably use the width and height of `Control.ClientRectangle` instead. I know that for a PictureBox, this gives the actual available dimensions for an image displayed on it.